# .gitignore excluding files in all directories

Tags: git, gitignore

In .gitignore I have

```
phpmyadmin
.idea
config.php
admin/config.php
system/cache/*
system/logs/*
image/cache/*
```

git is somehow ignoring `config.php` file in `system/library/config.php` why that can happen ? and how to avoid that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and exclude the file from the gitignore rules at that path:

```
config.php
!system/library/config.php
```

See more at [`gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> [The] prefix "`!`" negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again.
>   <del>It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded</del>

Note that with git 2.9.x/2.10 (mid 2016?), it might be possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded [if there is no wildcard in the path re-included](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d589a67eceacd1cc171bbe94906ca7c9a0edd8c5#diff-7fea460d44f92f185e7add8aa5620305R144).

[Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds) is trying to add this feature:

- [commit 506d8f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/506d8f1b394917c345965fc1762afa66678870c1) for git v2.7.0, reverted in [commit 76b620d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76b620d8166bf4cc7cadbc61f9927799ceea9162) git v2.8.0-rc0
- [commit 5e57f9c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e57f9c3dfe7dd44a1b56bb5b3327d7a1356ec7c) git v2.8.0-rc0,... reverted(!) in [commit 5cee3493](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5cee349370bd2dce48d0d653ab4ce99bb79a3415) git 2.8.0-rc4.

Answer (score 2):

If you include a filename (or glob) that doesn't contain a `/`, Git will ignrore files that match anywhere in your directory tree.

If you want to ignore only config.php in the top-level directory, you can add a leading slash to ensure that it only matches at the top level:

```
/config.php
```

As the [`.gitignore` documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) (`man gitignore`) states:

> - If the pattern does not contain a slash /, Git treats it as a shell glob pattern and checks for a match against the pathname relative to the location of the .gitignore file (relative to the toplevel of the work tree if not from a .gitignore file).
> - Otherwise, Git treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for consumption by fnmatch(3) with the FNM_PATHNAME flag: wildcards in the pattern will not match a / in the pathname. For example, "Documentation/*.html" matches "Documentation/git.html" but not "Documentation/ppc/ppc.html" or "tools/perf/Documentation/perf.html".
> - A leading slash matches the beginning of the pathname. For example, "/*.c" matches "cat-file.c" but not "mozilla-sha1/sha1.c".

Answer (score 0):

Adding !system/library/config.php as suggested by @VonC should work.
As for why it's ignored in the first place, try looking at your global gitignore
rules or file. It's possible there are leftovers from an older project.